# Mouse based parallax breaks when hovering over <a> tags

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've set up a little script that causes an image to slowly follow the mouse, creating a parallax effect. To make it feel a bit less janky, I added a small bit that checks if the mouse leaves the body, to just reset the animation. Unfortunately, that addition is making it so whenever I hover over an `<a>`, very briefly the parallax resets. The effect is most visible when you mouse onto an `<a>` and immediately stop moving the mouse.

I've tried switching between `$(document).mouseout` and `$('body').mouseout` to no avail.

```js
$.fn.parallax = function(resistance, mouse) {
  $e = $(this);
  gsap.to($e, 0.2, {
    x: -((mouse.clientX - window.innerWidth / 2) / resistance),
    y: -((mouse.clientY - window.innerHeight / 2) / resistance)
  });
};


$('body').mousemove(function(e) {
  $('.mouse-with img').parallax(-10, e);
});
$('body').mouseout(function() {
  gsap.to($('.mouse-with img'), 0.5, {
    x: 0,
    y: 0
  });
});
```

```css
html {
  font-size: 16px;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  font-size: 1em;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Sans-serif;
  color: #000;
  line-height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.mouse-with {
  margin: -150px 0 0 -200px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
}

a {
  position: fixed;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script><script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.5.1/gsap.min.js"></script>
<div class="mouse-with">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/400/300" alt="" />
</div>
<a href="tel:123-456-7890">123 456-7890</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is to check if `relatedTarget` of `mouseout` is within `body`:

```js
$.fn.parallax = function(resistance, mouse) {
  $e = $(this);
  gsap.to($e, 0.2, {
    x: -((mouse.clientX - window.innerWidth / 2) / resistance),
    y: -((mouse.clientY - window.innerHeight / 2) / resistance)
  });
};


$('body').mousemove(function(e) {
  $('.mouse-with img').parallax(-10, e);
});
$('body').mouseout(function(e) {
  if (!$(e.relatedTarget).closest('body').is(this))
  gsap.to($('.mouse-with img'), 0.5, {
    x: 0,
    y: 0
  });
});
```

```css
html {
  font-size: 16px;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  font-size: 1em;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Sans-serif;
  color: #000;
  line-height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.mouse-with {
  margin: -150px 0 0 -200px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
}

a {
  position: fixed;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script><script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.5.1/gsap.min.js"></script>
<div class="mouse-with">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/400/300" alt="" />
</div>
<a href="tel:123-456-7890">123 456-7890</a>
```